# Installing MySQLdb specifically in python 2.7 on centos

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, centos, mysql-python

I'm using CentOS release 6.5 (Final).

I 'm currently using python 2.4, in which I can use MySQL without problems.

```
root@dedicado [/home/digicelc/public_html/gestion/python/cater]# python
>>> import MySQLdb
>>>
```

But, when I try it from python2.7

```
root@dedicado [/home/digicelc/public_html/gestion/python/cater]# python2.7
>>> import MySQLdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named MySQLdb
>>>
```

I don't want to change the python version in the server, just want to make the module avaiable for 2.7

Finally this:

```
# yum install python27-MySQL-python
```

Is giving me this:

```
Error: Package: python27-MySQL-python-1.2.3-9.el6.centos.alt.x86_64 (scl)
           Requires: libmysqlclient_r.so.16()(64bit)
Error: Package: python27-MySQL-python-1.2.3-9.el6.centos.alt.x86_64 (scl)
           Requires: libmysqlclient_r.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: How did you install that python2.7? From source? From a package? From an SCL package? You are going to need to find a matching source for a 2.7 compatible mysql python module most likely.

Comment: I think from source, how can I do that?

Comment: You find the source for the python mysql module and built it against the python 2.7 that you installed from source. Though I would suggest not doing that if you can avoid it and instead (if this is CentOS 6) look into the SCL stuff that was announced recently as I believe that has what you want in it

Comment: I'm not having any luck, package yum install python27-MySQL-python ask me for some dependencies but I cannot solve them. (Error: Package: python27-MySQL-python-1.2.3-9.el6.centos.alt.x86_64 (scl)
           Requires: libmysqlclient_r.so.16()(64bit)
Error: Package: python27-MySQL-python-1.2.3-9.el6.centos.alt.x86_64 (scl)
           Requires: libmysqlclient_r.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
)

Comment: Which SCL's have you enabled?

Comment: I've done this yum install centos-release-SCL

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52326/discussion-between-etan-reisner-and-user1532587)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Had to install python2.7 to get a particular library, then couldn't run mysql via python2.7 because it was installed on 2.6.

Try this:
   pip2.7 install MySQL-python