# How to get mysql on an ec2 centos box with upgraded python

Tags: python, mysql, linux, gcc, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to get to a MySql database through python, starting with a centos ec2 instance with python upgraded to 2.7 from 2.6. It's not working because my gcc compiler cannot find a the python header file. `which python` returns `/usr/bin/python`, and `which gcc` returns `/usr/bin/gcc`.

The following is what I've tried.

Thanks to [a comment by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380931/installing-mysql-python-on-centos) @romuloigor, the discussion in chat/comments at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23546452/installing-mysqldb-specifically-in-python-2-7-on-centos?rq=1) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23764062/no-module-named-mysqldb-even-if-mysql-python-installed?lq=1) for the missing file `Python.h`, my method is the following:

```
sudo yum install mysql mysql-devel mysql-libs 
sudo yum install python-devel
sudo yum install MySQL-python 
sudo pip install mysql-python
```

I think if you've upgraded your python (say, from 2.6 to 2.7) this won't yet work. You need to put the path of the `Python.h` header file searchable by `gcc` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12379929/cant-find-python-h-file-on-centos) and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558803/how-to-add-a-default-include-path-for-gcc-in-linux)) by doing the following after `python-devel` is installed but before pip installing `mysql-python`:

```
find / -name Python.h 2>/dev/null # find path
```

Mine was at `/usr/include/python2.6/Python.h`:

```
C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/python2.6
sudo su
export C_INCLUDE_PATH
exit
echo $C_INCLUDE_PATH # should look right
```

Note, you can't use the `gcc -I` option because we can't access the c source file gcc is compiling because it's a pip install, and all the files are temporary.

Now, this still doesn't work. How would you tell gcc to find the header file?

PS. I think this question should be on stackoverflow because the FAQ states "Software development tools" and SO suggested the tags; please feel free to correct if you think differently!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AHA!

It was because I'd installed python2.7 alongside the system python2.6 (following [this great page](http://toomuchdata.com/2014/02/16/how-to-install-python-on-centos/)). I had to be careful that I referenced *the right python* ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624511/upgrade-python-without-breaking-yum)) and [from this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23215535/how-to-install-python27-devel-on-centos-6-5) I discovered my problem: `python27-devel` instead of `python-devel` was needed. Ah, ignorance.

Here's the final thing I ran.

```
sudo yum install mysql mysql-devel mysql-libs 
sudo yum install python27-devel
sudo yum install MySQL-python 
sudo pip install mysql-python
```